# Is the set of limit points $A'$ for a set $A$, contained in the set of limit points of $A'$?

Tags: general-topology

That the set of limit points $A'$ is closed is a well poundered question here, and it is strongly linked to the inclusion $(A')' \subset A'$

Now for the real line, with standard topology. I tried to proof that for a closed set $A$ the other inclusion i.e. $A' \subset (A')'$ holds.

It turned out to be wrong.

Since I meant to prove that $(A')'= A'$ I was thinking, maybe by adding some conditions it would be possible.

Surely the equality $A'=(A')' holds if A is a closed interval. But this is already quite a stong condition.

My attemt:

"""

Take $ x \in A'$ arbitrary then since $A$ is closed $x\in A$.

For each neigborhood $U$ of $x$, $U\cap A \setminus \{x\} \neq \emptyset$. By definion of the limit points.

Therefore take an arbitrary neighborhoud of $x$ then, there exists an element $y \in U \cap A \setminus \{x\} $ , we suppose WLOG that $y < x$.

*Therefore $(x,y) \subset A$

For all $a \in [y,x]$ now $a \in A'$ and therefore $[y,x] \subset A'$.
Therefore $x \in (A')'$. 
"""
(The claim at the asterix is wrong in general.)

Comment: "Also for each ,,," is a not a sentence with meaning.  Therefore there is a y with no property other than being a real number for which you make an unwarranted claim.

Comment: Thank you for noticing this

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question? "... in its own limit points"  What is "it"?

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample.
Let $A = \left\{ 0, \dfrac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb N\right\}$.
$A' = \{0\}$.
$A'' = \varnothing$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much :)
My teacher posed the question in such way that I thought it had to be valid, but this seems like a valid counterexample.